# How to use Supabase query with React Hot Toast Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase, react-hot-toast

I'm developing an administration page to manage my website. I use Supabase for the Database and React Hot Toast for notifications.

I tried this code to implement Toast Promise:

```js
const addData = async () => supabase.from(table).insert(data)
toast.promise(addData(), { loading: 'Loading', success: 'Success', error: 'Failed'})
```

However the popup notification is always success regardless of insert query result.

What is the right implementation for this situation ?

### UPDATE:

Sorry for the missing details. What I mean "regardless of insert query result" is that, for example, when I try insert query without proper roles (which means blocked by Row Level Security), which returns a 401 Unauthorized error, but popup is still Success.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> However the popup notification is always success regardless of insert query result.

Is the promise always **resolved** upon insert, regardless if the insert query succeeded? If yes, then you will always land within the `success` callback (See [this](https://github.com/timolins/react-hot-toast/blob/d897ad82bee649d2c8a68b29d2c8d80c81ca22ac/src/core/toast.ts#L74)). The `error` case will only trigger if your promise rejects (See [this](https://github.com/timolins/react-hot-toast/blob/d897ad82bee649d2c8a68b29d2c8d80c81ca22ac/src/core/toast.ts#L81)).
You could check the resolved data within the `success` callback and see if your insert provides any kind of confirmation that something got inserted (I'm not familiar with Supabase). See the ["Advanced Section"](https://react-hot-toast.com/docs/toast#advanced) of `react-hot-toast` docs.

**Update:**

I've checked [Supabase docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/insert) for `insert` and apparently it seems to return an object like that:

```
{"status": 201, "statusText": "Created"}
```

So in your case, I suppose your promise resolves but maybe with a "failing" status code, e.g. something > `2xx` ([status codes](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/http-status-codes)).

Comment: @ramiz-watchtler Thanks for your answer! I've added some more information, hope you reply soon :)

Comment: @TrungKiên Sorry if I introduced any misunderstanding, but what I meant in my answer was - Supabase probably **resolves** the promise, even though the result is not "successful" (That means, that your toast will always show success - also see my repo reference). Therefore you'd probably need to add some additional check of the result from `addData()`.